# How to create a wrapper of List with a specific type

Tags: list, scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I am trying to create a wrapper of `List` with a specific type (e.g. `List[Int]`) such that methods that take an implicit `CanBuildFrom` parameter return an instance of my wrapper instead of `List`.

One possible solution, which feels rather heavyweight, is:

```
import scala.collection._
import generic.{CanBuildFrom, SeqForwarder}
import mutable.{Builder, ListBuffer}

class MyList(list: List[Int]) extends immutable.LinearSeq[Int]
                                 with LinearSeqLike[Int, MyList]
                                 with SeqForwarder[Int] {
  override def newBuilder: Builder[Int, MyList] = MyList.newBuilder
  protected override def underlying = list
}

object MyList {
  def newBuilder: Builder[Int, MyList] =
    new ListBuffer[Int] mapResult(new MyList(_))

  implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[MyList, Int, MyList] = {
    new CanBuildFrom[MyList, Int, MyList] {
      def apply(from: MyList) = from.newBuilder
      def apply() = newBuilder
    }
  }
}

val l1 = new MyList(List(1,2,3))

println(l1.isInstanceOf[MyList])
println(l1.map(_ + 1).isInstanceOf[MyList])
println(l1.filter(_ == 2).isInstanceOf[MyList])
```

Is there a better/easier way to create such a wrapper or did I miss anything important in the implementation of `MyList`?

**Edit:** A follow-up question is: Can this whole wrapper logic be put into `ListWrapper` classes or traits so that the above `MyList` can be implemented like this:

```
class MyList extends ListWrapper[Int, MyList]

object MyList extends ListWrapperFactory[Int, MyList]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far I know from reading this article:

http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html

your solution is the simplest one, if you want filter/map/etc. to all return instances of `MyList`. `newBuilder` is needed for ops like `filter`, and the implicit `CanBuildFrom` for ops like `map`, which may change the collection type.

What you should maybe do in your `CanBuildFrom` is this:

```
def apply(from: MyList) = from.newBuilder // call it on `from'
```

which ensures that a `map` on a statically-typed `MyList` which actually has a dynamic type that is a subtype of `MyList` will reuse that same dynamic type.

**Edit**: seems like there is a little something missing, for this `map` returns an instance of `List` and not `MyList`:

```
val l1: LinearSeq[Int] = new MyList(List(1, 2, 3))
println(l1.map(_ + 1)) // prints List(2, 3, 4)
```

it looks like this is also the case with the `RNA` example taken from the linked article. If it has static type `IndexedSeq[Base]` instead of `RNA`, a `map` on it returns a vector.

**Edit 2**: looks like this is a more general problem, discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660656).

Comment: The static type determines the `CanBuildFrom` that is used.

Comment: In fact, you can check this with Scala own collections. Try it with `BitSet` and `Set`, which is pretty similar to the example given.

Comment: @Daniel Yep, indeed. I tried to discuss this problem more generally in this question, but with little success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678682/should-scalas-map-behave-differently-when-mapping-to-the-same-type

Answer (score 1):

Regarding my follow-up question how to mixin the wrapper logic via classes or traits, this is what I came up with:

```
import scala.collection._

trait ListWrapper[Elem, Repr <: ListWrapper[Elem, Repr]]
    extends immutable.LinearSeq[Elem]
    with LinearSeqLike[Elem, Repr]
    with generic.SeqForwarder[Elem] { self: Repr =>

  def wrapperCompanion: ListWrapperCompanion[Elem, Repr]

  override def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[Elem, Repr] =
    wrapperCompanion.newBuilder
}

trait ListWrapperCompanion[Elem, Repr <: ListWrapper[Elem, Repr]] {
  def apply(elems: TraversableOnce[Elem]): Repr

  def newBuilder: mutable.Builder[Elem, Repr] =
    new mutable.ListBuffer[Elem].mapResult(apply)

  def canBuildFromWrapper: generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr, Elem, Repr] = {
    new generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr, Elem, Repr] {
      def apply(from: Repr) = from.newBuilder
      def apply() = newBuilder
    }
  }
}
```

Now `MyList` can be implemented by:

```
class MyList(val underlying: List[Int]) extends ListWrapper[Int, MyList] {
  def wrapperCompanion = MyList
}

object MyList extends ListWrapperCompanion[Int, MyList] {
  def apply(elems: TraversableOnce[Int]) = new MyList(elems.toList)

  implicit def canBuildFrom = canBuildFromWrapper
}
```

This is definitely better than having all the boilerplate code in `MyList`'s definition, but it is still a lot to write for making `MyList` just a wrapper for `List`.

Comment: Instead of passing `wrapperCompanion` in the constructor of your abstract class, make it an abstract def — true, the definition of `MyList` gets longer, but you'll save the space for the extra field that's now needed in each instance of `MyList`.

Comment: Good advice. I wanted to make the definition of `MyList` as short as possible and didn't worried too much about the implications.

Comment: You can also remove the `implicit def canBuildFrom` from `object MyList` and make that of `trait ListWrapperCompanion` implicit.

Comment: If I do this I get `error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method canBuildFrom in object LinearSeq of type [A]scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq.Coll,A,scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq[A]]
 and method canBuildFrom in trait ListWrapperCompanion of type => scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[this.MyList,Int,this.MyList]
 match expected type scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[this.MyList,Int,That]` when I call `map` on a `MyList`.