# extending scala collections with new attribute

Tags: scala, scala-collections

If I have a new collection with an additional attribute, e.g. :

```
class NewColl(var name: String, var values: Vector[Int])
    extends IndexedSeq[Int] with IndexedSeqLike[Int, NewColl] {...}
```

how do I define `canBuildFrom` and `newBuilder` (cf. [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html)) such that if:

```
var v1 = NewColl("foo",Vector(1,2,3))
var v2 = v1 filter(_ > 1)
var v3 = v1 map(_ + 1)
```

then `v2.name=="foo"` and `v3.name=="foo"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
class NewColl(val name: String, val values: Vector[Int])
    extends IndexedSeq[Int] with IndexedSeqLike[Int, NewColl] with SeqForwarder[Int] {
  override def newBuilder: Builder[Int, NewColl] = NewColl.newBuilder(name)
  protected override def underlying = values
}

object NewColl {
  def apply(name: String, elems: Vector[Int]) = new NewColl(name, elems)
  implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[NewColl, Int, NewColl] = {
    new CanBuildFrom[NewColl, Int, NewColl] {
      def apply(from: NewColl) = from.newBuilder
      def apply() = newBuilder(defaultName)
    }
  }
  private def newBuilder(name: String) = Vector.newBuilder[Int].mapResult(vector => new NewColl(name, vector))
  private def defaultName: String = error("no default name")
}
```

Note that I've changed your `var`s into `val`s here to be consistent with an immutable collection. `SeqForwarder` has been mixed in to avoid implementing a list of methods that would all forward to the same method on `values`. `newBuilder` has been implemented on the companion object and needs a `String` parameter.

Note that sometimes, collections are free to call `apply()` on the `CanBuildFrom` without specifying the originating collection. In that case, you either have to provide a default name, or (like here) throw an exception (permissible only if you're not designing a library and control the use of your new collection).

See also [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5659893/390581).

Comment: Great seems to work!!!Can you please explain more in details why mixing `SeqForwarder` is needed?

Comment: It's not strictly needed, it just allows you to skip defining methods that would be forwarded to the `values` vector, like `def size = values.size`.

Comment: SeqForwarder has been deprecated in 2.11.0