# Extending collection classes with extra fields in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm looking to create a class that is basically a collection with an extra field. However, I keep running into problems and am wondering what the best way of implementing this is. I've tried to follow the pattern given in the Scala book. E.g.

```
import scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

class FieldSequence[FT,ST](val field: FT, seq: IndexedSeq[ST] = Vector())
        extends IndexedSeq[ST] with IndexedSeqLike[ST,FieldSequence[FT,ST]] {

    def apply(index: Int): ST = return seq(index)
    def length = seq.length

    override def newBuilder: Builder[ST,FieldSequence[FT,ST]]
        = FieldSequence.newBuilder[FT,ST](field)
}

object FieldSequence {

    def fromSeq[FT,ST](field: FT)(buf: IndexedSeq[ST])
        = new FieldSequence(field, buf)

    def newBuilder[FT,ST](field: FT): Builder[ST,FieldSequence[FT,ST]]
        = new ArrayBuffer mapResult(fromSeq(field))

    implicit def canBuildFrom[FT,ST]:
            CanBuildFrom[FieldSequence[FT,ST], ST, FieldSequence[FT,ST]] =
      new CanBuildFrom[FieldSequence[FT,ST], ST, FieldSequence[FT,ST]] {
        def apply(): Builder[ST,FieldSequence[FT,ST]]
            = newBuilder[FT,ST]( _ ) // What goes here?
        def apply(from: FieldSequence[FT,ST]): Builder[ST,FieldSequence[FT,ST]]
            = from.newBuilder
      }
}
```

The problem is the CanBuildFrom that is implicitly defined needs an apply method with no arguments. But in these circumstances this method is meaningless, as a field (of type FT) is needed to construct a FieldSequence. In fact, it should be impossible to construct a FieldSequence, simply from a sequence of type ST. Is the best I can do to throw an exception here?

Answer (score 0):

Then your class doesn't fulfill the requirements to be a `Seq`, and methods like `flatMap` (and hence for-comprehensions) can't work for it.

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm still left with the problem of how to implement something which does this. Perhaps a default from an abstract method on FieldSequence?

Comment: Do you really need inheritance? Or is composition good enough, having a wrapper class taking care of the special initialization of the Seq? The wrapper could still implement something weaker like `Traversable`, and delegate it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you would count my solution as inheritance or composition. I don't know how those terms work with Scala as opposed to more traditional languages. I think you were getting at a sort of pimped pattern, but since I control the class I didn't think it necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I agree with Landei about `flatMap` and `map`. If you replace with throwing an exception like this, most of the operations should work.

```
def apply(): Builder[ST,FieldSequence[FT,ST]] = sys.error("unsupported")
```

From what I can see in `TraversableLike`, `map` and `flatMap` and most other ones use the `apply(repr)` version. So for comprehensions seemingly work. It also feels like it should follow the Monad laws (the field is just carried accross).

Given the code you have, you can do this:

```
scala> val fs = FieldSequence.fromSeq("str")(Vector(1,2))
fs: FieldSequence[java.lang.String,Int] = FieldSequence(1, 2)

scala> fs.map(1 + _)
res3: FieldSequence[java.lang.String,Int] = FieldSequence(2, 3)

scala> val fs2 = FieldSequence.fromSeq("str1")(Vector(10,20))
fs2: FieldSequence[java.lang.String,Int] = FieldSequence(10, 20)

scala> for (x <- fs if x > 0; y <- fs2) yield (x + y)
res5: FieldSequence[java.lang.String,Int] = FieldSequence(11, 21, 12, 22)
```

What doesn't work is the following:

```
scala> fs.map(_ + "!")
// does not return a FieldSequence

scala> List(1,2).map(1 + _)(collection.breakOut): FieldSequence[String, Int]
java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported
// this is where the apply() is used
```

For `breakOut` to work you would need to implement the apply() method. I suspect you could generate a builder with some default value for `field`: `def apply() = newBuilder[FT, ST](getDefault)` with some implementation of getDefault that makes sense for your use case.

For the fact that `fs.map(_ + "!")` does not preserve the type, you need to modify your signature and implementation, so that the compiler can find a `CanBuildFrom[FieldSequence[String, Int], String, FieldSequence[String, String]]`

```
implicit def canBuildFrom[FT,ST_FROM,ST]:
        CanBuildFrom[FieldSequence[FT,ST_FROM], ST, FieldSequence[FT,ST]] =
  new CanBuildFrom[FieldSequence[FT,ST_FROM], ST, FieldSequence[FT,ST]] {
    def apply(): Builder[ST,FieldSequence[FT,ST]]
        = sys.error("unsupported")
    def apply(from: FieldSequence[FT,ST_FROM]): Builder[ST,FieldSequence[FT,ST]]
        = newBuilder[FT, ST](from.field)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it made me think about things in order to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my answer was very similar to that in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659893/how-to-create-a-wrapper-of-list-with-a-specific-type). The difference with that question and my original and the answer are slight but basically allow anything that *has* a sequence to *be* a sequence.

```
import scala.collection.SeqLike
import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

trait SeqAdapter[+A, Repr[+X] <: SeqAdapter[X,Repr]]
        extends Seq[A] with SeqLike[A,Repr[A]] {
    val underlyingSeq: Seq[A]
    def create[B](seq: Seq[B]): Repr[B]

    def apply(index: Int) = underlyingSeq(index)
    def length = underlyingSeq.length
    def iterator = underlyingSeq.iterator

    override protected[this] def newBuilder: Builder[A,Repr[A]] = {
        val sac = new SeqAdapterCompanion[Repr] {
            def createDefault[B](seq: Seq[B]) = create(seq)
        }
        sac.newBuilder(create)
    }
}

trait SeqAdapterCompanion[Repr[+X] <: SeqAdapter[X,Repr]] {
    def createDefault[A](seq: Seq[A]): Repr[A]
    def fromSeq[A](creator: (Seq[A]) => Repr[A])(seq: Seq[A]) = creator(seq)
    def newBuilder[A](creator: (Seq[A]) => Repr[A]): Builder[A,Repr[A]] =
        new ArrayBuffer mapResult fromSeq(creator)

    implicit def canBuildFrom[A,B]: CanBuildFrom[Repr[A],B,Repr[B]] =
        new CanBuildFrom[Repr[A],B,Repr[B]] {
            def apply(): Builder[B,Repr[B]] = newBuilder(createDefault)
            def apply(from: Repr[A]) = newBuilder(from.create)
        }
}
```

This fixes all the problems huynhjl brought up. For my original problem, to have a field and a sequence treated as a sequence, a simple class will now do.

```
trait Field[FT] {
    val defaultValue: FT

    class FieldSeq[+ST](val field: FT, val underlyingSeq: Seq[ST] = Vector())
            extends SeqAdapter[ST,FieldSeq] {
        def create[B](seq: Seq[B]) = new FieldSeq[B](field, seq)
    }

    object FieldSeq extends SeqAdapterCompanion[FieldSeq] {
        def createDefault[A](seq: Seq[A]): FieldSeq[A] =
            new FieldSeq[A](defaultValue, seq) 
        override implicit def canBuildFrom[A,B] = super.canBuildFrom[A,B]
    }
}
```

This can be tested as so:

```
val StringField = new Field[String] { val defaultValue = "Default Value" }
StringField: java.lang.Object with Field[String] = $anon$1@57f5de73

val fs = new StringField.FieldSeq[Int]("str", Vector(1,2))
val fsfield = fs.field
fs: StringField.FieldSeq[Int] = (1, 2)
fsfield: String = str

val fm = fs.map(1 + _)
val fmfield = fm.field
fm: StringField.FieldSeq[Int] = (2, 3)
fmfield: String = str

val fs2 = new StringField.FieldSeq[Int]("str1", Vector(10, 20))
val fs2field = fs2.field
fs2: StringField.FieldSeq[Int] = (10, 20)
fs2field: String = str1

val ffor = for (x <- fs if x > 0; y <- fs2) yield (x + y)
val fforfield = ffor.field
ffor: StringField.FieldSeq[Int] = (11, 21, 12, 22)
fforfield: String = str

val smap = fs.map(_ + "!")
val smapfield = smap.field
smap: StringField.FieldSeq[String] = (1!, 2!)
smapfield: String = str

val break = List(1,2).map(1 + _)(collection.breakOut): StringField.FieldSeq[Int]
val breakfield = break.field
break: StringField.FieldSeq[Int] = (2, 3)
breakfield: String = Default Value

val x: StringField.FieldSeq[Any] = fs
val xfield = x.field
x: StringField.FieldSeq[Any] = (1, 2)
xfield: String = str
```